# How to use sim cards on ubuntu 21.10. WWAN requirements are satisfied with the system

Tags: lenovo, thinkpad, wwan

I have a lenovo x1 carbon thinkpad. I purchased it with WWAN capabilities enabled but, I have never used it. I inserted the sim card into the slot. What do I have to do next? It is not auto initializing. Following are the WAN related available parts in my machine

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: use a sim card to connect to the internet

Comment: Oh dear god No :D. Basically, my laptop has a sim slot and all the other hardware needed for the said purpose. I should be able to use the mobile network of that sim to connect to the internet. I just don't know how